# Tap Gesture on List View Items

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to open another view after tapping on an item in the list view.
I have tried adding a `TapGestureRegonizer` and even adding `ViewCell` with grids etc. None of these seem to work. I have added a tap gesture to a label and that seemed to work but the same does not work for list view items. This seems like a simple problem for something like list view, but there doesnt seem to be a built in functionality for this.

The Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="dataList"
      ItemsSource="{Binding routeLabels}"
      HasUnevenRows="True"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.Column="0"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
</ListView>
```

The code behind:

```
var listviewgesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
listviewgesture.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty,"LoadRoutePage");
dataList.GestureRecognizers.Add(listviewgesture);
```

The view model:

```
public ICommand LoadRoutePage { get; protected set; }



public DriverDashboardViewModel(INavigation navigation,MessagDatabase database)
    {
        this._database = database;
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        this.LoadNotifications = new Command(async () => await OpenNotificationsPage());
        this.LoadRoutePage = new Command(async () => await OpenRoutePage());

    }

public async Task OpenRoutePage()
    {

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new RoutePageView());
    }
```

Just to be clear the `LoadNotifications` method does work in opening a page but `LoadRoutePage` does not. So I know there is some level of communication between the view and viewmodel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not be adding a `TapGestureRecognizer` to a `ListView`. Every cell already has events that handle tapping on them and a GestureRecognizer would probably only confuse the `ListView` regarding what the tap should be doing. There are a few ways to go about this.

**1. SelectedItem binding**

Bind a `SelectedItem` property to the `ListView` and handle your method calls in the setter of that property.

```
<ListView x:Name="dataList" ItemsSource="{Binding routeLabels}"
          HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"        
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
</ListView>
```

And in your viewmodel:

```
string _selectedItem;

public string SelectedItem {
    get {return _selectedItem; } 
    set 
    { 
        _selectedItem = value;
        // Additional code
    }
}
```

**2. Use the built in events ItemSelected or ItemTapped**

A `ListView` has some events you can hook up named `ItemSelected` and `ItemTapped`. These can be caught in code-behind and can handle what you're trying to achieve.

```
<ListView x:Name="dataList" ItemsSource="{Binding routeLabels}"
          HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"        
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">
</ListView>
```

**3. Use event to command binding with behaviors**

Since you use viewmodels you ideally don't want these events since they're handled on the UI side. There are NuGet packages out there that can translate an event to a Command that you can handle in your viewmodel. Take a look at [Corcav.Behaviors](https://github.com/corradocavalli/Corcav.Behaviors) for example.

**4. Create a behavior of your own**

I have one I use regularly which looks like this:

```
public class ListViewSelectedItemBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ListViewSelectedItemBehavior));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public ListView AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(ListView bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        AssociatedObject = bindable;
        bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
        bindable.ItemSelected += OnListViewItemSelected;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(ListView bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;
        bindable.ItemSelected -= OnListViewItemSelected;
        AssociatedObject = null;
    }

    private void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnBindingContextChanged();
    }

    private void OnListViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Command == null)
            return;

        if (Command.CanExecute(e.SelectedItem))
            Command.Execute(e.SelectedItem);
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;
    }
}
```

To add this to your `ListView` you simply add a behavior to it:

```
<ListView x:Name="dataList" ItemsSource="{Binding routeLabels}"
          HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"        
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:ListViewSelectedItemBehavior Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

In this case `ItemSelectedCommand` is a Command object in your ViewModel.

Comment: I will take a look at these and let you know, thank you.

Comment: In option one you have the property Route _selectedItem, what is that type Route supposed to represent?  Im not sure

Comment: It's the type of items that are bound to your ListView. Since the code refers to the ListView containing Routes I assumed that the items bound to the ListView were Route objects. If it's e.g. a list of strings change it to `string`.

Comment: ahh I see. Its a collection of strings but thanks for the context.

Comment: Changed the sample to match your situation :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but you are trying to get an event going when someone taps on anelement of a listview?

If so you don't need a recognizer you simply have to add ItemTapped in your XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="dataList"
      ItemsSource="{Binding routeLabels}"
      HasUnevenRows="True"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.Column="0"
      ItemTapped="Name of event"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
</ListView>
```

This will generate an event for you ( just do double tab when creating the ItemTapped ) and here you can place your code

Answer (score 0):

You're binding a command instead of an event to the "Tapped" event. Try something like this:

code behind:

```
var listviewgesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
listviewgesture.Tapped += Handle_listViewItemTapped;
dataList.GestureRecognizers.Add(listviewgesture);
```

ViewModel:

```
private void Handle_listViewItemTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.OpenRoutePage();
}
```