# Xamarin command is not working for object of Observablecollection

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and currently working on a solution in which I am facing the below problem.
I have a class A which is my Model class, and Class B which is my viewModel.
   Model Class

```
Class A  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string sampleprop { get; set; }
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

I am creating objects of Class A as observable collection in Class B.

```
Class B
    {
   public Command<string> CallCommand { get; set; }
   public ObservableCollection<A>   AobjectsCollection { get; set; }

   public B()
        {
            AobjectsCollection = new ObservableCollection<A>();
            CallCommand = new Command<string>((string arg) => 
    DoMakeCall(arg));
        }
    public void DoMakeCall(string phNumber)
        {
            string s = phNumber;
        }
}
```

Assigning Class B as my Binding context for Main view page.

```
public partial class Mainview : ContentPage
 {
    InitializeComponent ();
         BindingContext = new B();
  }
```

In Main view(xaml) I am creating a listview with ClassB's observable collection property.

```
     <ListView x:Name="MessagesListView" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding AobjectsCollection }"
                 HasUnevenRows="True" >
                 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                     <ViewCell >
                         <ViewCell.View>
             <Button x:Name="btnClick" Text="ClickMe" 
                    Command="{Binding CallCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="sampleprop"/> 
             </ViewCell.View>
                         </ViewCell>
                   </DataTemplate>
                 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

Now Clicking on button(btnClick) in main page is not invoking the command of my viewModel and execute my method DoMakeCall(string s).

Could anyone please help me to understand on what is wrong in this code? and how can I achieve this scenario?

My Command property is with the VM class and not in Model class. Only thing what I need to find out is how to set the context properly to make it work. I don't want to use relay command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RelayCommand parameter passing in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812035/relaycommand-parameter-passing-in-xamarin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently binding each ViewCell to your A model. It has no reference to the B ViewModel (which is where the command resides that you want to call. To fix this, you need to tell the ViewCell Button to look for the command on the MessagesListView's BindingContext (Your B ViewModel in this case). That would look like this:

```
BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference MessagesListView}, Path=BindingContext}"
```

And in full context:

```
 <ListView x:Name="MessagesListView" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding AobjectsCollection }"
           HasUnevenRows="True" >
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell x:Name="viewCell">
                       <ViewCell.View>
                           <Button x:Name="btnClick" Text="ClickMe"
                                 BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference MessagesListView}, Path=BindingContext}" 
                                 Command="{Binding CallCommand}" 
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference viewCell}, Path=BindingContext}"/> 
                       </ViewCell.View>
                   </ViewCell>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for this scenario. But when I have List<someotherclassobject> instead of Sampleprop in classB, how can I set the current object(someotherclassobject) as commandParameter? As we set the Bindingcontext for button to the ModelView, I am not able to get the current object of populated listview. I have tried with CommandParameter ={Bindig .}, but it didnt worked. :( can you help me?

Comment: I added some code to make the commandparameter bind to the cell's original viewModel, which would be your instance of ClassA I think. Your command would then accept that instance of ClassA that is bound to the ViewCell that you clicked on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Binding ViewCell is not working, It throws runtime exception. I have tried with ViewCell and ViewCell.BindingContext... But no luck :'(

Comment: @ Will Decker. Finally it worked with below code <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MessagesListView} , Path=BindingContext.CallCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

Comment: Your solution helped me to resolve a similar problem where my button's command (The button is in a ListView's DataTemplate) could not fire. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using button, I suggest you to use `ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected`.

```
<ListView x:Name="MessagesListView" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AobjectsCollection }"
          HasUnevenRows="True" 
          ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected">
```

You can refer here : [Tap Gesture on List View Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946780/tap-gesture-on-list-view-items?rq=1)

The explaination is very detail. Hope it helps.